# Memsetting pointer to an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memset

I have a pointer to an array. I know how many number of items that array can hold but the length of each item is dynamic. So how to `memset()` the array in this case.

```
Int8 *data[4]; //array can hold maximum of 4 elements
```

Also I want to allocate memory for each item. How to do this?

Comment: You'd probably be best using [calloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc). That will allocate and memset the values, plus "feels right" for an array.

Comment: Isn't that rather an array of pointers?

Comment: "I have a pointer to an array." - no, you have an array of pointers. I concur with Undur. A pointer to an array would would like `Int8 (*data)[4];`

Answer (score 1):

First, you initialize the array at definition time by saying,

```
Int8 *data[4] = { NULL };  //NULLify all the elements.
```

Then, you need to use a loop to allocate memory to each element of the array, like

```
for (index = 0; index < 4; index++)
    data[index] = calloc(SIZE, sizeof(Int8)); //SIZE is a MACRO
```

FWIW, [`calloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) will returned "zero"ed memory (if success), so no need to `memset()` separately if you want the memory to be initialized to `0`.

Obviously, you need to check for the success of the allocation.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, absolutely. My connectivity was down, so late in modifying. Thanks. :-)

Comment: I suspected. This is as close to what I can fathom the question was about. so have an uptick =P

Comment: @WhozCraig Appreciate your time and effort for review and the suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First I would sizeof the individual elements. Use a for loop and recurs the number of elements within your declaration.

Set the sizeof return equal to an integer so that you can access it, then memset with that integer for each element.

```
Int8 *somedata;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {    // for i less than 4 do increment i
    memset(data[i], somedata, sizeof(data[i]));   // memset data at point i, with value somedata, which has a size data[i] 
}
```

Hope that gives you something to go on!

Comment: `sizeof( data[i] )` returns the size of the **pointer**, not what it's pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main ( void )
{
        int *pointer_array[4],i=0;

/* Allocating memory and storing the address in pointer_array[] */
        for ( i=0; i<4; i++ )
        {
                pointer_array[i] = malloc ( sizeof(int) );
        }

/* Memset the values with 0 */
        for ( i=0 ;i<4; i++ )
        {
                memset( pointer_array[i], 0 , sizeof(int) );
        }
/*printing the values */
        for ( i=0 ;i<4; i++ )
        {
                printf ( "\n %d", *pointer_array[i] );
        }
/* deallocating the memory */
        for (i=0; i<4; i++ )
        {
                free ( pointer_array[i] );
        }

        return ( 0 );

}

output:
rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$ ./a.out 

 0
 0
 0
 0rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$
```